# How do I interact with a collection in a helper but only return a specific output not the entire collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

In my view, I have this:

```
<% node.tagged_users.each do |tagged_user| %>
   <li><%= display_avatar_or_email(tagged_user) %></li>
<% end -%>
```

But, what I am trying to do is create a helper method that whenever there are say 5 `tagged_users`, it will show the avatars for the last 3, then show a link on the text "2 more" or "2+" (per the image below). Note, it shouldn't show the total users tagged, just the difference between the number of tagged users currently being shown as avatars and the total number of tagged users for this particular node.

So it would look something like this:

[image]

Not sure if it matters, but the method for `display_avatar_or_email(tagged_user)` looks like this:

```
  def display_avatar_or_email(user)
    link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url, size: "48x48", :class => "img-circle", title: user_name_or_email(user)), user
  end
```

I have a method for the `tagged_users.count`:

```
  def total_tagged_users_count(node)
    node.user_tags.count
  end
```

When I moved the entire `node.tagged_users.each do |tagged_user|` into my helper, it spat out the entire AR collection in my view - which is not what I want. I just want the result of the logic, not everything within the method.

What's the best way to do this in a helper, in a Rails-way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a helper to spit out html use a content_tag or write raw html as strings. I kinda like the content_tag.

```
def some_helper node
  node.tagged_users.first(3).each do |tagged_user|
    content_tag(:li, display_avatar_or_email(tagged_user))
  end
  content_tag(:li, (node.tagged_users.count - 3))
end
```

Comment: I would do a slight change just to keep things clean `node.tagged_users.first(avatar_count = 3).each` then below use `node.tagged_users.count - avatar_count` this way the number is not duplicated in 2 places, and one change will reflect in the other

Comment: Ahh...interesting optimization @MohammadAbuShady. Thanks.

Comment: @daslicious - I was trying to figure out a way to iterate over the collection from within the helper (not the view). But doubt it can work.

Comment: Ahh...right.... `content_tag`....that's what I was missing! Awesome. Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.each` in the helper you created..shouldn't you use `.map`? Then the implicit return would be the result of that, not the each loop across your collection.

Comment: What is being returned to the view though? Is it every single line within the method? How do I keep track of each avatar shown, up to the limit, without it being output to the view? i.e. I would normally just do a local variable within the method, and increment/decrement that way. But if that local variable is being sent to the view, that doesn't quite work.